# Does Bitfinex support B2X? Will BTC holders at the moment of the fork be credited B2X on a 1:1 ratio?

Tags: exchanges, segwit2x, bitfinex

I know, we should hold them in cold storage, etc, but I can't know for sure whether Bitfinex will credit the B2X on a 1:1 ratio for BTC holders.

Thank you for your answers!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most exchanges will not credit you the same day but make you wait a certain amount of time. Your best bet is to withdraw and extract it yourself if you want 2x coins quickly.

Answer (score 2):

There's no 2X fork anymore now, since it has been [called off](https://twitter.com/lopp/status/928309280507351040?s=09)